# Soft spots on subfloor, how to fix (laminate installation)

Tags: floor, subfloor, laminate-floor

When preparing to install laminate in a room, I discovered two soft spots on the subfloor after I removed old carpet and underlayment. Here is what they look like:
[image]

The spots are a few inches (10-20 cm each, see above) and are in the middle of the room (far from the window). Also, I did not notice any water marks or any signs of water damage. The house is roughly 30 years old.

How to fix this properly? Do any conservative methods exist (no subfloor replacement)? Finally, should I be worried about them at all given the task (laminate installation). It seems (I might be wrong) like laminate planks and underlayment on top will spread pressure evenly over a larger surface, so this may be unnoticeable.

Comment: What do you mean by "soft", how much movement, and how large an area? Does it squeak? Can you see the floor structure from below (unfinished basement /crawlspace?) What kind of laminate product? Most I've seen are fairly thin/flexible and will not bridge a "large" low/soft spot.

Comment: @blarg The movement is visible if someone steps on it (I would say, at least 0.5 cm). It does not squeak. I cannot see the structure form below, it is on the second floor. The area is shown on the picture (magnify to see the ruler). I plan to lay 12 mm thick LifeProof laminate planks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those spots are truly *soft* and not just *sunk*, you have two options:

1. Live with it.
2. Repair it.

If you choose Option 2, and you don't have access from an unfinished room below (basement), you'll have to cut out the soft subfloor, block between the joists, and replace the subfloor.

Comment: the movement is visible if someone steps on this spot (I would say, at least 0.5 cm). I guess it qualifies as sunk. I assume I will have to replace the entire subfloor plywood board where the soft / sunk spot belong to. Is this correct?

Comment: No, you don't need to replace the entire board (usually these things are 4x8 ft in size in the US.  You sound like you're in Eastern Europe, so it looks like standard size is 2500x1250 mm.  That's a lot of replacement.  I'm assuming you have floor joists, and are not on a concrete slab.  What you'd do is cut out the soft spot only (20 cm), then get some lumber and make a box that you slide into the hole, like this: https://youtu.be/bXbOeOtHvyM?t=325

Comment: thanks for your help. I am in North America actually. What's is the standard thickest of plywood boards used for subfloor for newer construction?

Comment: 23/32 is what most subfloor is nowadays.  But you should measure what you actually have—depending on age, it could be different, and you'll want it to match the rest of your floor's thickness (unless you elect to replace the entire subfloor).